# Eclipse Debugging Not Showing

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I had a working eclipse configuration, but I accidentally deleted that whole eclipse set up. I tried downloading newer eclipse (seeing as I couldn't recall the eclipse version I had), and it functions, however it has a really strange, and really annoying behavior; when hit the debug button it runs right through, but when I set a break point it seems to stop at the break point, but doesn't indicate it anywhere in the program. It doesn't show the line with a green highlight as it usually should. Perhaps it has something to do with my JRE/JDK? I tried the different JRE versions 6-8. Maybe it has to do with my debug configuration. Any help on your experience with or understanding of debugging would be greatly appreciated.
Here is what happens when I click the debug button:
[image]

Comment: Are you running in debug mode? Sounds like a stupid question, but you have no idea how many people make these kinds of mistakes.

Comment: Debug mode meaning? I am definitely clicking the debug button, and I can tell it is running, because it runs through the rest of the program until it hits a break point and then it stops, however it doesn't let me look at anything.

Comment: Maybe you've updated into a change you're not familiar with. My eclipse (kepler) shows a blue arrow over the blue break point; no green highlight. Settings perhaps?

Comment: I updated the post with a visual of a simple example of what occurs.

Comment: Oh goodness, apparently it only functions with the debug view.

Comment: If it's solved, post an answer. Help other people :)

Comment: It is solved. I will.